# Macro or dynamic placeholder in appledoc

Tags: documentation, documentation-generation, appledoc

In my iOS project, I added screenshot images to the documentation of some classes.
The documentation is generated with [appledoc](http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc/).

Basically, for the class `TheViewController`, this would look like this:

```
/**
 * A view controller: awesome and helpful class description.
 *
 * **iPhone Screenshot:**
 * ![](../docs/documentation_data/ViewControllersScreenshotsGallery/screenshots/TheViewController_iPhone.png)
 *
 * **iPad Screenshot:**
 * ![](../docs/documentation_data/ViewControllersScreenshotsGallery/screenshots/TheViewController_iPad.png)
 */
```

**Is there any way to DRY this?**
A macro, pre-processing (via `preprocess-headerdoc`?), dynamic placeholder, script, options fed to appledoc?

Ideally, I would like to just have this:

```
/**
 * A view controller: awesome and helpful class description.
 *
 * SCREENSHOTS_FOR_IPAD_AND_IPHONE
 */
```

---

Bonus point if I don't even have to add the line `SCREENSHOTS_FOR_IPAD_AND_IPHONE`, and the content is only added if some condition is met (ie, if images are found where expected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time there's no such functionality.